# Agens Graph get inherits

Tags: agens-graph

I'm using AgensGraph and want to be able to inspect the inheritance between vectors.

So if I write:

```
CREATE VLABEL labelName;
CREATE VLABEL childLabelName inherits (labelName);
```

I can use \dGv I can view which vector inheritance details, but is there way to use SQL or Cypher to view get a list subclasses and superclasses?